How do I get this star pattern to work with only one for loop in python?
Very new to python and coding in general!
Trying to get a star pattern that looks like this:
*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*

to work using a for loop, but I'm only allowed to use a single for loop, and embed an if/else statement inside to get it to work. If I could use 2 for loops I'd know how to do it but not sure why my current solution isn't working, as it only outputs the first 5 lines of stars and then stops. Any help appreciated :)
My current codebase:
print("Pattern: ")

# Stores the * as a variable, not entirely necessary but negates having to type out "*" 
star = "*"

for i in range(9):
    if i in range(5):
     print(star * (i + 1))
    elif i in range(4, 0, -1):
       print(star * i)


Consider what happens when i is 6. It is neither in range(5), nor in range(4, 0, -1).

print(list(range(4,0,-1))) to see why it doesn't work.  Think of what i value is.

Once i gets to 5, it is neither in the range 0-4 nor the range 4-0 (and in fact those two ranges are practically identical), and so your code does not print anything.

I think you meant to have range(5, 9) as your second check.

Just use else: and a little more math on the print.

Thanks a lot for all the suggestions guys, got it working now :)

As others have mentioned in the comments, your range() structure is flawed.
You can simplify the approach by using > and < in your if else like this:


print("Pattern: ")

star = "*"

for i in range(9):
    if i < 5:
        print(star * (i + 1))
    else:
        print(star * (9 - i))




Here is a very concise solution
string = '*****'

for i in range(9):
    print(string[abs(4-i):])

The loop goes through values of i 0 to 8. For values 0 - 4 the abs (absolute value) can be ignored, so 4-i will resolve to 4, 3, 2, 1 and 0. When i > 4, 4-i will be negative, but after taking the absolute value of the result, you get 1, then 2, then 3 and finally 4. It then uses the value returned by abs(4-i) to splice the string, with the index of the return value to the end of the string.

range(4, 0, -1) contains the integers [4, 3, 2, 1], all of which are already part of range(5), so the code in the elif branch will never execute. You can directly use an else to handle the values of i not in range(5). However, star * i is the wrong expression to print, as the number of asterisks will increase as the loop continues, but the bottom half of the pattern should have a decreasing number of stars; star * (9 - i) would work to that effect.
You could use min to avoid an explicit branch as well like so:
star = "*"
size = 9
for i in range(size):
    print(star * min(i + 1, size - i))

Or, with a generator expression:
print('\n'.join(star * min(i + 1, size - i) for i in range(size)))


Simply and easy to understand.
def draw_star(num):
    
    for i in range(num):
        
        if i<num // 2:
            stars = i+1
        
        elif i== num//2:
            stars = stars
        else:
            stars = num-i
            
        print("*" *stars)
        
draw_star(9)

and for your code it should be like that. Because your loop never range(4,0,-1) that part. That's why ur program stop at middle.
print("Pattern: ")

# Stores the * as a variable, not entirely necessary but negates having to type out "*" 
star = "*"

for i in range(9):
    if i in range(5):
     print(star * (i + 1))
    elif i in range(9, 5, -1):
       print(star * (9-i))

